# How can I train a model that takes in the word vectors on each side and predicts the middle word?

Tags: python, lstm, word-embedding

How can I train a model that takes in the word vectors on each side and predicts the middle word?

I have created word embeddings of the 2 words preceding the middle word (word to replace) and the 2 words after the middle word. I would like to see code on how to feed this into an LSTM model, which I have seen only take in one vector to predict the word after.